# What the meaning of "|" and "&" in the if statement of Verilog

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

I saw the following Verilog if statement code. Wanted to know what's the meaning/purpose of "|" and "&" before the the dl and dl_n? Anyone kind to explain? Or what's the keyword I should look for from google for this?

```
if((count_w > 1) && ~(|dl==1'b0 && &dl_n==1'b1)) begin
//Statements
end
```

Comment: Here is a good example of [Reduction Operators](https://www.nandland.com/verilog/examples/example-reduction-operators.html).

Answer (score 1):

These are called [reduction operators](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html) in Verilog.

`|` is used as an `OR`, and the `&` used as an `AND`.

Following are the reduction operators:

```
| Operator|   Type  |
|_________|_________|
|   &     | And     |
|  ~&     | Nand    |
|   |     | Or      |
|  ~|     | Nor     |
|   ^     | Xor     |
|  ~^     | Xnor    |
|_________|_________|
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the *unary reduction* operators. `|val` is reduction OR, and `&val` is reduction AND.

Answer (score 0):

Reduction operators:

- & (AND)
- ~& (NAND)
- | (OR)
- ~| (NOR)
- ^ (XOR)
- ~^ or ^~ (XNOR)

Nevertheless, don't confuse with "&&" as this is a local AND. Also, the reduction should be right next to the variable, if positioned between two variables like "a & b" , it is a bit-wise operation, an example:

```
wire c = &a ^ |b;
/* The value of a has an AND reduction,
   b an OR reduction,
   and the results of those reductions takes a bit wise XOR operation between them,
   this assigned to c.*/
```

[image]